I am getting 400 Bad Request error on Post Request
I have built an MVC application which includes CRUD methods for a user to update some data. The controller for the update UI makes an HTTP call to another MVC controller, which is in my microservices application. My problem is that some of the data coming into the microservice controller has null properties.
I am trying to update the product details. I click on the button on the product and it redirects me to the product details of this product. The data for this product is transferred correctly, I am trying to update the product details but it does not work
when I am trying to update the product information in the postman, thr updete process works
//ProductDetail Service
public class ProductDetailService : IProductDetailService
{

    public async Task<GetByIdProductDetailDto> GetByProductIdProductDetailAsync(string id)
    {
        var values = await _productDetailCollection.Find<ProductDetail>(x => x.ProductID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<GetByIdProductDetailDto>(values);
    }

    public async Task UpdateProductDetailAsync(UpdateProductDetailDto updateProductDetailDto)
    {
        var values = _mapper.Map<ProductDetail>(updateProductDetailDto);
        await _productDetailCollection.FindOneAndReplaceAsync(x => x.ProductDetailID == updateProductDetailDto.ProductDetailID, values);    
    }
}

// ProductDetail ApiController (Microservice)
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProductDetailsController : ControllerBase
{
   
    [HttpGet("GetProductDetailByProductId")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductDetailByProductId(string id)
    {
        var values = await _productDetailService.GetByProductIdProductDetailAsync(id);
        return Ok(values);
    }

    
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> updateProductDetail(UpdateProductDetailDto updateProductDetailDto)
    {
        await _productDetailService.UpdateProductDetailAsync(updateProductDetailDto);
        return Ok("Ürün Detayı Başarılıyla Güncellendi");
    }
}

//ProductDetail Controller (WebUI)
 [Area("Admin")]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [Route("Admin/ProductDetail")]
 public class ProductDetailController : Controller
 {
     [Route("UpdateProductDetail/{id}")]
     [HttpGet]
     public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProductDetail(string id)
     {
         var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
         var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7070/api/ProductDetails/GetProductDetailByProductId?id=" + id);
         if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             var jsonData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpdateProductDetailDto>(jsonData);
             return View(values);
         }
         return View();
     }
     [Route("UpdateProductDetail/{id}")]
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProductDetail(UpdateProductDetailDto updateProductDetailDto)
     {

         var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
         var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateProductDetailDto);
         StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
         var responseMessage = await client.PutAsync("https://localhost:7070/api/ProductDetails/", stringContent);
         if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             return RedirectToAction("ProductListWithCategory", "Product", new { area = "Admin" });
         }
         return View();
     }
 }


400 Bad Request shows that the request you sent to another API is not able to be processed. Have you tried using the Postman to post the content like you did in the code? If it still encounters same error, that means your request body is incorrect, you need to revise request body, make sure that it fulfills the data type, validation etc.

If via Postman works fine, that means you are not sending the request correctly in your code. You also can try to debug and read the Content in your last screenshot. It should tell you why it returns a 400 error.

There's a lot of code to go through there. Please edit the post to reduce it to a minimal reproducible example.

Also, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Have you checked if your Serializer / Deserializer Case sensitivity is configured the same way in API and MVC application?
MVC usually uses Camel Case by default and API lower Camel Case. It may be the reason why you are getting null values in the API.
You can use either: JsonPropertyName attribute on models or set the following during serialization: JsonSerializerOptions

yes I check out the Serializer / Deserializer Case Sensitivity this is correct. Also I am tried the JsonPropertyName attribute and JsonSerializerOptions. This is not works

Client side code/model sample and viewmodel used at controller samples may be better for exact problem. But it seems, this is a Model Binding problem.
Are you sure jsonData is same json with POSTMAN json?
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateProductDetailDto);

TLDR;
Check Json serilazation (Postman is good but not allways! adding its own salts at behind)
Means check sent body as Json and Model is fitting by field names.!
At start of the project you can manage/decide how the Model Bindin will work by JsonSerializerOptions called.
xxx.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy

